# Excel Chart Fixed Position

Tags: excel, charts

Is there anyway to keep a chart visible whilst scrolling through the raw data?

Normally the chart rolls up/down with the data.

Thanks,

Comment: You can use View->New Window and then Arrange All -> Arrange Vertical so each side of the sheet is in a separate window.

Answer (score 0):

Usually the same way as you would fix a row or cell

https://support.office.com/en-us/article/freeze-panes-to-lock-rows-and-columns-dab2ffc9-020d-4026-8121-67dd25f2508f

Comment: Yes I've tried that but it looks ugly. You have to move the data away from the chart and lock the chart area. My raw data is left hand side and the chart is on the right. I hoped there was a way of making the chart float so as I scroll the data rolls down but the chart fixes.